# Is It Possible To Do Hunger Games Without Downloading Anything?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

After watching Stampylonghead videos, I noticed that the Hunger Games looked really cool. In the description it said I had to download it. Is it possible to play Hunger Games without downloading it? BTW, my external servers are not working and I am on MineCraft PE and Console. I have both.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot play Hunger Games without downloading the map unless you build it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do it.
As far as I know there is no special plug-in that Hunger Games using on Minecraft.

If you have lots of free time you can build a map and put all the items and things together. Hide them, create places etc.

and... well yeah. You will have your very own hunger games map.
And yes, you can do it on pocket edition.

Since you don't need to download anything and do all the things by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to download the mod to be able to apply the rules:
- Freeze people in place when they enter the world
- Sound shots when someone dies
- Move the player who died out of the game

These are just some examples.

But as tommythelittleguy says: it is possible to re-create the map.
But then you only have the map, but not the rules...

Answer (score -1):

You would need a lever and redstone for the host so no.